# Simple Diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation, abc-conjecture

Are there any solutions in positive integers of
$x^3 + 1 = (x - k) y^3$?

The closest I can get is
$19^3 + 1 = 20 \times 7^3$,
but $20\gt 19$ so it just misses!

For the related
$x^3 - 1 = (x - k)  y^3$,
I find
$18^3 - 1 = 17 \times 7^3$
which works, but no other solutions. Is the similarity of these examples a coincidence?

Comment: That is no coincidence since $\frac{(n+1)^3+1}{(n+1)+1}=\frac{n^3-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: It is still a coincidence. Combining them leads to (18^2+18+1)=7^3 and thence to (37^2)+3=4*7^3 and this is the only nontrivial solution to x^2+3=4y^3 according to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044095/what-are-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-x2-x1-y3

Comment: Notice that for a solution, $y$ cannot be prime or prime power. Indeed, your equation is equivalent to demanding that $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)/y^3$ be a positive integer less than $x$. If $p$ is the only prime divisor of $y$, then since $\gcd(x+1, x^2-x+1)$ is $1$ or $3$, we would get $p=3$ (otherwise $(x+1)(x^2-x+1)/y^3$ would be at least $x+1$). However, $x^2 - x + 1$ is never divisible by $9$, so this cannot happen.

Comment: For fixed $k$ one can determine all the integral solutions $(x,y)$ using the identity $$(x-k)(x^2+kx+k^2-y^3)=-k^3-1.$$ There are no solutions with $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$ and $1\leq k\leq 30000.$ If $k<-1,$ then there are positive solutions like $(x,y,k)=(9,1,-721),(26,3,-625).$